# spark datagrid bind image url issue

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flash-builder, flex-spark

I have following rss, and I want to bind title and image to spark datagrid

```
<item>
<title>LOS ANGELES (AP) — Michael Jackson&amp;#39;s doctor was quietly freed from jail on Monday, two years after he was convicted of killing the pop superstar with an</title>
<pubDate>Tue, 29 Oct 2013 04:34:38 GMT</pubDate>
<guid isPermaLink="false">tag:obsrv.com,2009:item-d409113f8dde0c428cd550bc9e2cd91d</guid>
<media:content url="http://ww2.hdnux.com/photos/06/15/51/1628761/3/628x471.jpg" type="image/JPEG" medium="image" fileSize="61KB" height="471" width="583" /> 
<media:title>LOS ANGELES (AP) — Michael Jackson&amp;#39;s doctor was quietly freed from jail on Monday, two years after he was convicted of killing the pop superstar with an</media:title>
<media:description>http://www.obsrv.com/FeedItems/ShowFeedItemsPage.aspx?FeedItems=4796333</media:description>
<media:thumbnail url="http://ts2.mm.bing.net/th?id=HJ.69931579597&amp;pid=15.1' alt='' style='width:221.47659063625px;height:179px;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px;' /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;" />
<description>&lt;a href=http://www.obsrv.com/FeedItems/ShowFeedItemsPage.aspx?FeedItems=4796333 target="_blank" &gt;&lt;img src='http://ww2.hdnux.com/photos/06/15/51/1628761/3/628x471.jpg' width='320px' /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br/&gt;www.sfgate.com&lt;br/&gt;29/10/2013 4:34:38 AM GMT</description>
<link>http://www.obsrv.com/FeedItems/ShowFeedItemsPage.aspx?FeedItems=4796333</link>
</item>
```

and I am writing spark datagrid as shown below:

```
<s:DataGrid id="dgNews" x="10" y="150" width="300" height="545" color="#000000" visible="true" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" 
            variableRowHeight="true"  selectionColor="#e1ecf9" click="dgNews_clickHandler(event)">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>               
            <s:GridColumn dataField="title" headerText="Technology" width="300"/>               
            <s:GridColumn dataField="content" headerText="Qty" width="198">
                <s:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <s:GridItemRenderer>
                            <s:VGroup>
                                <s:Image source="{data.content}" height="198" width="198" >

                                </s:Image>                                  
                            </s:VGroup>

                        </s:GridItemRenderer>
                    </fx:Component>
                </s:itemRenderer>
            </s:GridColumn> 
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

and when I am run this project I got title but in image column I got no image in it.

Or simply I want to display image in column from

can any one suggest what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that `content` property bindable?

Comment: original format & url for image is in                               <media:content url="http://ww2.hdnux.com/photos/06/15/51/1628761/3/628x471.jpg" type="image/JPEG" medium="image" fileSize="61KB" height="471" width="583" /> I want url="http://ww2.hdnux.com/photos/06/15/51/1628761/3/628x471.jpg" from this....